# How change the default font size of a particular font mid document?

Tags: fonts, xetex, stackengine

I am using  XeLaTeX(fontspec) and I have the following  problem. I am using a lot of differents fonts in the preamble like

```
\setmainfont{GFSDidot}    
\newfontfamily{\greekfont}{CMU Serif}
 \newfontfamily{\greekfontsf}{CMU Sans Serif}
  \newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{Linux Libertine O}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
```

and I use `stackengine` package to stack differents fonts. I would  like to change locally the font size   for one particular font without affecting the size of the other fonts that are used together in the stack process. I am afraid that   the command `\addfontfeatures[Scale=..]` will affect the size of any font in the stack! So my question is: Is it possible  to change the font size of a particular font locally (without the need  to define a new `\newfontfamily` for this particular font and with the desired size)?  Something like {`\addfontfeatures{\hebrewfont}[Scale=..]`  ....} ?
You could use the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{Linux Libertine O}
\newunicodechar{ǎ}{\accent\string"02C7 a}
\newunicodechar{א}{{\hebrewfont{א}}}
\newunicodechar{ע}{{\hebrewfont{ע}}}
\begin{document}
\stackengine{\Lstackgap}{ǎ}{א}{O}{c}{F}{\useanchorwidth}{L}\\
{\fontspec{\hebrewfont} \addfontfeature[Scale=0.8] \stackengine{\Lstackgap}{ǎ}{א}{O}{c}{F}{\useanchorwidth}{L}}
\end{document}
```

Also I have the same problem when I tried to define a "scaled" command something like `\newcommand\hebr[1]{\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}\addfontfeature{Scale=#1}}` 
Then the output of `{\hebr{0.3}ǎא }` is not the  expected one!!

Comment: So in this case you want to make א smaller but leave ǎ the same size?

Comment: @David Carlisle Yes! I would like to make small font size changes in a particular font inside a particular stack! Thanks!

Comment: I can't persuade your code to compile, by the way. Nothing but errors.

Comment: @cfr! Yes, indeed. The code before \fontspec{\hebrewfont} is indeed OK. The problem exists after that. I think that \fontspec has some problems. You cannt pick a font using \fontspec{\hebrewfont} . You have to use explicitly its name  Linux Libertine Oafter \fontspec... The problem is irerevalent with stackengine package! Thanks for your interest!

Comment: You're not supposed to say `\fontspec{\hebrewfont}`, though, so it isn't surprising it doesn't work. At least, that is not how it usually is used. Do you see something in the manual which suggests this *should* work? The point of saying `\newfontfamily\fontfamilyname`, as I understand it, is that you can then say `\fontfamilyname` without calling `\fontspec` explicitly. In the case of Polyglossia, defining `\hebrewfont` enables automatic switching to the appropriate font when Hebrew is active. But your code doesn't enable support for Hebrew.

Comment: I also cannot get your code to compile, but if your goal is to scale one row in a stack, I would just place that row in a `\scalebox{.8}{א}`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If the font to be scaled always appears at the same level in the stack (for example, always on the top), then one can set up a macro, here `\mystackon`, that scales the upper element of the stack.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{Linux Libertine O}
\newunicodechar{ǎ}{\accent\string"02C7 a}
\newunicodechar{א}{{\hebrewfont{א}}}
\newunicodechar{ע}{{\hebrewfont{ע}}}
\newcommand\mystackon[2]{%
  \stackengine{\Lstackgap}{#1}{\scalebox{.8}{#2}}{O}{c}{F}{\useanchorwidth}{L}%
}
\begin{document}
Unaltered:
\stackengine{\Lstackgap}{ǎ}{א}{O}{c}{F}{\useanchorwidth}{L}
Revised:
\mystackon{ǎ}{א} \mystackon{b}{ע}
\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, if one needed the smaller font on demand, in arbitrary locations, one could create the macros `\smallhebrew` and `\normalhebrew` as directives on changing the font size.  This is accomplished through a redefinition of `\hebrewfont` to include (or not) a scaling.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{Linux Libertine O}
\newunicodechar{ǎ}{\accent\string"02C7 a}
\newunicodechar{א}{{\hebrewfont{א}}}
\newunicodechar{ע}{{\hebrewfont{ע}}}
\let\svhebrewfont\hebrewfont
\newcommand\smallhebrew{\renewcommand\hebrewfont[1]{\scalebox{.8}{\svhebrewfont{##1}}}}
\newcommand\normalhebrew{\let\hebrewfont\svhebrewfont}
\begin{document}
normal: \stackengine{\Lstackgap}{ǎ}{א}{O}{c}{F}{\useanchorwidth}{L}
\stackengine{\Lstackgap}{ע}{ǎ}{O}{c}{F}{\useanchorwidth}{L}
%
small: \smallhebrew%
\stackengine{\Lstackgap}{ǎ}{א}{O}{c}{F}{\useanchorwidth}{L}
\stackengine{\Lstackgap}{ע}{ǎ}{O}{c}{F}{\useanchorwidth}{L}
%
back to normal: \normalhebrew%
\stackengine{\Lstackgap}{ǎ}{א}{O}{c}{F}{\useanchorwidth}{L}
\stackengine{\Lstackgap}{ע}{ǎ}{O}{c}{F}{\useanchorwidth}{L}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My compliments for your works with LaTeX. Hi.